# Outlook adds a space below logo image

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm retrofitting an HTML email template so that it works on mobile devices. Basically it's a two column message, and I'm reflowing the columns. There are some conditional comments for Outlook, and divs with `inline-block` for Gmail since it doesn't have media queries, and it works fairly well.

One issue I've been unable to solve is in the header. There's a logo image, a date next to it, and a border underneath both. The border needs to be at the very bottom of the logo image, but Outlook 2010 and 2013 on Windows (Outlook 2011 on Mac, as well as outlook.com and Office 365 and every non-Outlook client are fine) put a space in between.

Here's the HTML I'm using for the header, specifically. I've included the wrapping elements, but not the rest of the content.

```html
<center style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    <div>
      
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="600" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->
        <table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #1a1818; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; Margin: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; width: 100%">
          <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom-color: #000; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 10px; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 0; Margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center" align="center">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="50%" valign="bottom">
            <![endif]-->
              <div style="display: inline-block; Margin-right: 0; max-width: 390px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%">
                <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #1a1818; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; Margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 0; height: 90px; line-height: 0px; Margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align: bottom" valign="bottom">
                      <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #1a1818; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; Margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; text-align: left; width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 0; height: 90px; line-height: 0px; Margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align: bottom" valign="bottom">
                            <a href="browserversion" style="color: #1A1818; text-decoration: none"><img src="logo" alt="alt text" width="390" height="90" align="left" style="border: 0 none; display: block; height: auto; line-height: 100%; Margin: 0; max-height: 90px; max-width: 390px; outline: none; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%" /></a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                  </td><td width="50%" valign="bottom">
            <![endif]-->
              <div style="display: inline-block; Margin-right: 0; max-width: 210px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%">
                <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #1a1818; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; Margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; height: 90px; line-height: 100%; Margin: 0; padding: 10px 0 5px; text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%" align="right" valign="bottom">
                      <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #1a1818; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; Margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; text-align: left; width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; height: 90px; line-height: 100%; Margin: 0; padding: 10px 0 5px; text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%" align="right" valign="bottom">
                            September 25, 2015
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
            </td> <!-- end .two-column.header -->
          </tr> <!-- end row -->
        </table> <!-- end .outer -->
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <![endif]-->

    </div>
  </center>

  </body>
</html>
```

There are so many things out there to remove space from images in Outlook, and I've implemented all the ones I've been able to find, but so far there has been no luck. Here's a screenshot of the issue as it appears in Outlook.

[image: Outlook]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this. I added these styles to the header (so the first `td` that isn't commented out needs a header class):

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
.header table { font-size:1px; line-height:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This solution was found here: http://www.optimisedemail.com/2013/05/the-weekly-fix-outlook-2013-spacing.html